# executing batch files parallel and wait till all completes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a `master batch` file which calls another list `batch` files. I want to wait until all the `batch` files are executed (*cannot say which one will execute faster*) and comes to `master batch` file to execute the remaining.

Example:

```
           a) master.bat            b) build.bat
              call build.bat           start web.bat        
              post.bat                 start db.bat
```

here `master.bat` calls a file `build.bat` and `build.bat` files runs the `web & db bat` files in parallel and once they are executed, it has to return to `master.bat` and run the `post.bat`.

can any one please guide me how to do this.

Comment: See [Parallel execution of shell processes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11715437/1012053). You should be able to adapt that script fairly easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for parallel batch scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577442/waiting-for-parallel-batch-scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the resolution but forgot to update :)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "lock=%temp%\wait%random%.lock"

:: Launch processes asynchronously, with stream 9 redirected to a lock file.
:: The lock file will remain locked until the script ends.
start "" 9>"%lock%1" web.bat
start "" 9>"%lock%2" db.bat

:Wait for both processes to finish (wait until lock files are no longer locked)
1>nul 2>nul ping /n 2 ::1
for %%N in (1 2) do (
  (call ) 9>"%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait
) 2>nul

::delete the lock files
del "%lock%*"

:: Finish up
echo Done - ready to continue processing.
```

Thanks,

Comment: you seemed to copy the code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665498/995714) without citing the source

Comment: what is web.bat and db.bat? Quite strange, you hook your own answer without explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using an **[additional tool](http://www.videohelp.com/software/MParallel)** – the Windows command processor doesn't support this "out of the box" – you can do it like this **without** the need for "busy waiting" or using "lock" files:

```
mparallel.exe --count=3 --shell first.bat : second.bat : third.bat
call post.bat
```

First line will start `first.bat`, `second.bat` and `third.bat` *in parallel*. It will **not** return until all three have terminated. We use `--shell` here to run tasks in a shell, which is required for BAT files. After the three BAT's have completed, `post.bat` is executed. Could be another *mparallel* call though.

Answer (score 0):

Within master.bat:

```
:flagfloop
set "flagfile=%temp%\%random%%random%%random%"
if exist "%flagfile%*" goto flagfloop
call build
:wbuild
if exist "%flagfile%*" timeout /t 10 >nul&goto wbuild
post.bat
```

Within build.bat

```
for %%i in (web db) do (
 echo.>"%flagfile%%%i"
 start %%i.bat
)
```

Within web.bat and db.bat, just before the batch exits,
     del "%flagfile%%%~n0" >nul 2>nul

Which should select a random tempfile-prefix; create the files 123321123web and 123321123db for the duration of the third-level `.bat`s and then proceed with the main routine when both have finished (The timeout is set to 10 sec; your option to change this as necessary)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicated of [Wait For Commands to Finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946535/wait-for-commands-to-finish/6961589#6961589)

You may use several flag files, one per running Batch file. Master Batch file may create Flagfile.1 when enter, and the called Batch file may delete it before end.

The master Batch file just must wait for all flagfiles disappear. For example, in master file:

```
echo X > flagfile.1
start build.bat 1 arg1
echo X > flagfile.2
start build.bat 2 arg2
.....
:wait
if exist flagfile.* goto wait
post.bat
```

In any build.bat Batch file:

```
echo Do my process...
del flagfile.%1
exit /B
```

Comment: can you please elaborate with repect to my given example

Answer (score -2):

Use  [CALL command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) as below:

**master.bat** :

```
call build.bat              
call post.bat
```

Comment: The OP explicitly asked how to run the scripts in parallel. Your code runs them sequentially.